# Get Messages from any channel using Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Is there a way to get messages which could be receiving in any channel in socket.io  like plain web-sockets, something like,

```
socket.on('*' , (data) => {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io doesn't handle it natively but someone wrote a middleware to handle wildcards: https://github.com/hden/socketio-wildcard

Example from the Readme:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.use((packet, next) => {
    // Handler
    next();
  });
});
```